# Styling divs created from array onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have an array like this `const divs = ["Text 1","Text 2","Text 3"]`.
I create divs (a small menu) from this array in my render function

```
var createThreeDivs = divs.map((category) => {
        return <div key={category} onClick={this.handleClick} className="myDivClass">{category}</div>
});
```

I want to style one of these divs when i click on them, and the remove the styling on the rest of them. So when i select one of the divs it gets a color and removes the color on the rest of them

In normal javascript with no virtual DOM i could do like this:

```
handleClick(e) {

    //remove styling from others
    var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("myDivClass");
    for(var i = 0; i < allDivslength; i++) {
        allDivs[i].classList.remove("myDivClass-styled");
    }

    //Add styling class to selected,
    e.target.classList.add("myDivClass-styled");

}
```

But this manipulate the DOM directly. How do i do something like this in React?

I have seen examples of how this can be done using state with only one element and by not having an array creating the divs. But i can't come up with a good solution for this scenario. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the component's state you can update the color based on the active `div`. Update the index of the active div when the user clicks, and when the index equals the div that was clicked on update the color of that div.

See example below.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
       active: 0 
    };

  }
    
  render() {
    
    const divs = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];
    
    const updateActiveDiv = (value) => {

       this.setState(() => {
           //this line will reset the value to 
           //null if same element is clicked twice
           if(value === this.state.active) {
             value = null;
           };

           return {
             active: value
           }
    
      });

    };
    
    let divText = divs.map((div, i) => {

      let color = this.state.active === i ? 'red' : 'black';
      return <div style={{ color }} onClick={() => updateActiveDiv(i)}>{div}</div>;
      
    });

    return (
       <div>
         { divText }
       </div>
    );
  }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! If i want to click on the active div and then remove the styling, how can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass current text from html
 handleClick = (text)=>{
this.setState({activeText:text})
}

Inside create div function add class dynamically 

Div className = { stat condition ? Class : no class }
```